# How do you delete a lines within a file where range is determined using regular expressions in python?

Tags: python, regex, lines

I am trying to clean up a series of text files by deleting unneeded lines.  I want to delete lines starting with the line that matches Regex1 and keep deleting until the line with Regex2 is found.  I need to do this using python.  I have already done this using a sed command something like

`sed -r '/regex1/,/regex2/d'`

and had good luck, but I need something I can run on Windows machines.  Plus, I want the whole solution to be using one language instead of piping between shell and python scripts.  Anyone have any ideas or posts to point me to?

Comment: A) You could use cygwin to run sed on windows. B) You may want to take a look at python's `re` package.

Comment: just a recommendation: there is a big "V" at the left of each answer below. If one of them solved your problem - as you have said it solved - just click on it to make it clear that it is the correct answer for your question. In fact, try to do it at every question you asked and you've got an acceptable answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using [`re.DOTALL`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) to make `.` match newlines:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"regex1.*?regex2", re.DOTALL)
```

You can then use `pattern.sub("", data)` to delete the lines.

Comment: Don't use this if your file is really big.

Answer (score 2):

```
import sys,re

reg_start = 'reg1'
reg_end = 'reg2'

to_print = 1

for line in sys.stdin.readlines():
    if re.search(reg_start, line):
        to_print = 0
    elif re.search(reg_end, line):
        to_print = 1

    if to_print:
        print line,
```

Answer (score 0):

In perl there's flip-flop operator that can be use as :

```
perl -ne "print unless /regex1/ .. /regex2/" file
```

you could convert this to python as it's explain [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/python-list@python.org/msg55280.html)